# Google cloud platform/App Engine - Error: certificate has expired - where is this coming from?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I have a two services hosted on App Engine. They've been working fine for a couple of years.

About 40 minutes ago both services suddenly started logging this error over and over:

```
Error: certificate has expired
at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1502:34)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:937:8)
at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:711:12)
```

That isn't part of my code and the services seem to be running normally except for the error being logged every few seconds.

The App Engine SSL certs have not expired and I have no idea what other certificate the error could be referring to.

I'm not sure how to track down the problem. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction?

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: I would recommend you to contact GCP support.

Comment: Do you use ssl connection to postgres anywhere in your code or to any other services?